# Returning the time of the first activity

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a table, which stores all of the activities of the day.  I want to be able to pull the time of the first activity of today.  However, my query isn't returning any values.  I have checked the data and it looks like it is stored correctly within the table (Text field / days and months in the right place).  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT Min(Activity_Start) AS ExprStart 
FROM tblActivity 
WHERE [Activity_Start] BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+1 day')"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your activity_start format is '*%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S*' where as `DATE('now')` returns `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')`. The comparatives are in wrong format! Try the below;

```
SELECT MIN(Activity_Start) AS FirstActivity
FROM tblActivity
WHERE Activity_Start >= strftime('%d/%m/%Y', date('now'))
```

Comment: Same result I'm afraid.  My system is setup for the UK, and whilst the data looks correct (06/04/2014 12:00:00), I'm wondering if the problem could be with the query trying to give me a US date?

Comment: Can you post what `DATE('now')` returns on your system/server and a what actually is the first value in **Activity_Start** for today?

Comment: Here you go - Activity_Start = 06/04/2014 13:58:11 / DateTime.Today.ToString() = "06/04/2014 00:00:00"

Comment: Ahh - thank you.  I am using parameters within my insert query (date variable previously set using now), but is there a specific format that I should use during the insert?

Comment: As per my limited understanding of sqlite, you seem to be doing it just right. I don't use sqlite too extensively, to have known this difference off hand.

Comment: Thank you athar13 - in the end I also changed how I add the date/time data to the table, as I was still getting the occasional weirdness (SQLite stores it as a text field).  After changing the insert parameter to convert the date to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" - everything became a lot easier.  Thanks again.